# Perl one-liner to remove trailing space from a file

Tags: perl

I am calling a perl one-liner inside a Perl script.

The intention of the one-liner is to remove the trailing space from a file.

Inside the main perl script:

```
`perl -pi -e 's/\s+$//' tape.txt`;
```

Now it is throwing me an error `Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 2.`

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: It would be a better design to not do this.  Why not just do what you need to do within your script, rather than calling another instance of Perl externally?

Comment: @dan1111 Here is the situation -there is an external program that make use of the input file before my script read the file. Now this external program is failing because of the trailing space in the file.
So I wanted to 1)remove the trailing space 2)pass the updated file to external program 3)Get the confirmation from the program 4)start doing stuffs with the file in the script

Comment: if doing something like this, always make sure your command is looking like you think it does: my $cmd = "perl -pi ..."; warn "cmd: `$cmd`"; `$cmd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backtick syntax invokes a shell and when invoked, the shell assumes it should interpolate the string passed.

A cleaner syntax might be:

```
system('perl -pli -e "s/\s*$//" tape.txt');
```

Since you aren't capturing the output of the command, using backticks or `qx` in lieu of `system` isn't an issue.

Too, adding the `-l` switch autochomps each line read **and** then adds a newline back --- probably what you want.

Answer (score 7):

It's because of the `$/` (special variable) inside your main perl script. Note that variables are interpolated inside ``` `` ``` strings just like inside `""` strings, and the fact that there are some single quotes in there doesn't change that. You need to escape that `$`:

```
`perl -pi -e 's/\s+\$//' tape.txt;`
```

Comment: you also need to escape the \s. if you had warnings turned on, you'd see: 'Unrecognized escape \s passed through '

Comment: `$cmd="perl -pi -e 's/\\s*\$//' tape.txt";`
`system($cmd);`
and now its replacing the \n char also
@tinita where is it breaking now?

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace. If you do not want to match newlines then replace `\\s*` with `[ ]*`, or if you want to match spaces and tabs, `[ \t]*`. If you want to preserve the newline, then `s/\\s*\\n\$/\\n/`.

Comment: thanks @Dan I got it working :)
this is my code now 
`$cmd_remove_tailing="perl -pi -e 's/\\s*\\n\$/\\n/' tape.txt";
system($cmd_remove_tailing);`

Answer (score 1):

\s matches [ \t\n\r\f] and do not want to match \n.

Notice use of {} for subst delimiters:

```
$ echo -e 'hi    \nbye'| perl -pe 's{[\t\040]+$}{};' | cat -A
hi$
bye$
```